# "\n" delimiters issue

Tags: java, delimiter

I have a stringbuilder object, that a line of data gets added to.

after each line gets added, I append a "\n" on the end to indicate a new line.

this stringbuilder object, finalised, gets written to a flat file.

When I open the flat file in notepad I get a small rectangle after every line and the column formatting is ruined.

When I open the flat file in wordpad, the new line is taken into consideration and the column formatting is perfect.

I have tried all ways I know of removing the new line entry before it gets written, but this removes the formatting when written to the flat file. I need the new line for the formatting of the columns.

how can I output the file with new lines but without using \n?

Comment: I found a great work around, I was using FileWriter to write to the file, instead I used PrintWriter, which has a println(); method. I allocated an empty string as the arguement (printwriter.println("")) and the file now keeps the formatting.

Comment: Notepad is broken, do not use Notepad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Windows way of terminating a line is to use "\r\n", not just "\n".

You can find the "line separator for the current operating system" using the `line.separator` system property:

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
...
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
...
builder.append(lineSeparator);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value for the system your Java program is running on from the system properties

```
public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `\n`. Since "nodepad", it is `\r\n`, for MS Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you should use \n\r. In *NIX (Linux/UNIX/Mac) u should use \n

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, you should be writing `\r\n` to get it to load properly in Notepad. The `\n` terminator is a Unix file ending, and Notepad won't parse it properly. Wordpad will convert them for you.

Also I suggest not using Notepad, and looking towards something like Vim.

Comment: Notepad users don't generally take to vim without a lot of difficulty.

Comment: True, true, but hope springs eternal :).

Comment: Notepad++ or Notepad2 would be an easier upgrade.