# Read formatted text from file using a scanner

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, delimiter, inputmismatchexception

I would like to read a file with the following format using a Scanner.

integer,integer

integer,integer

...

First I added, scanner.useDelimiter(",").

Then I used, scanner.nextInt() twice for the two integers and used scanner.nextLine() to get the scanner to the next row.

The problem occurs after this since it excpects the delimiter "," but the scanner is positioned at an integer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple delimiters in Scanner class of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898263/multiple-delimiters-in-scanner-class-of-java)

Comment: I tried using fileScanner.useDelimiter(",|\\n"); But it generates following exception "java.util.InputMismatchException", the second time that scanner.nextInt() is called.

Comment: Are you running on Windows?

Comment: Yes I am using Windows.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649362/n-delimiters-issue ?