# I can't get two String values in one string using templates

Tags: string, kotlin, templates, concatenation, stringtemplate

I got some function:

```
    private fun selectHometown() = File("data/towns.txt")
    .readText()
    .split("\n")
    .shuffled()
    .first()
```

And if I try to get or print some string with the 2 values obtained from this function, the first value disappears. For example:

```
println("${selectHometown() ${selectHometown() }")
```

Will only print one city name, while I expect two. I guess the problem is related to string concatenation in Kotlin. Of course, I can get the desired result in a different way, but I'm wondering why this one doesn't work.

Comment: Your `println()` is missing a `}`; is that a typo in the question, or does it explain your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Windows way of terminating a line is to use "\r\n" so use it as delimiter :

```
private fun selectHometown() = File("data/towns.txt")
.readText()
.split("\r\n")
.shuffled()
.first()

println("${selectHometown()} ${selectHometown()}")
```

Comment: thank you. It works in your example, but it doesn't work when I try to read from file

Comment: Use "\r\n" as delimiter. you could see explanation here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649362/n-delimiters-issue)